# Subquery returns multiple rows in HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, having

I want to get the customer who mostly borrowed films of category 3 in 2016, July

```
SELECT c_firstName, c_lastName, rental.c_ID
FROM customer, rental
GROUP BY rental.c_ID HAVING rental.c_ID=MAX((SELECT COUNT(rental.c_ID) 
FROM customer, copies, rentalprocess, rental, film
WHERE customer.c_ID=rental.c_ID AND rentalprocess.r_ID=rental.r_ID AND
      rentalprocess.s_ID=copies.s_ID AND film.f_ID=copies.f_ID AND
      f_category=3 AND r_date LIKE "2016-07%" GROUP BY rental.c_ID))
```

But ir doesn't work because it said that the subquery returns more than one row

What can I do?

Comment: What rmdbs is this?  Oracle, MySQL etc?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: It is MySQL RMDBS

Comment: RDBMS, relational database management system :)

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Max()` is an aggregate function that needs to be in a select statement

```
SELECT 
  c_firstName
  , c_lastName
  , rental.c_ID
FROM customer, rental
GROUP BY rental.c_ID 
HAVING rental.c_ID=
  (
  select 
    MAX(i.iID) 
  from 
    (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(rental.c_ID) iID
    FROM customer, copies, rentalprocess, rental, film
    WHERE 
      customer.c_ID=rental.c_ID AND 
      rentalprocess.r_ID=rental.r_ID AND
      rentalprocess.s_ID=copies.s_ID AND 
      film.f_ID=copies.f_ID AND
      f_category=3 
      AND r_date LIKE "2016-07%" 
    GROUP BY rental.c_ID
    ) i
  )
```

In this case the sub-select returns multiple rows but then you take the max value of that query

Comment from Mr Linoff is correct, you should use explicity joins:

```
SELECT 
  c_firstName
  , c_lastName
  , rental.c_ID
FROM customer, rental
GROUP BY rental.c_ID 
HAVING rental.c_ID=
  (
  select 
    MAX(i.iID) 
  from 
    (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(rental.c_ID) iID
    FROM 
      customer 
      inner join rental 
        on customer.c_ID=rental.c_ID
      inner join rentalprocess 
        on rentalprocess.r_ID=rental.r_ID
      inner join copies 
        on rentalprocess.s_ID=copies.s_ID
      inner join film on film.f_ID=copies.f_ID
    WHERE 
      f_category=3 
      AND r_date LIKE "2016-07%" 
    GROUP BY rental.c_ID
    ) i
  )
```

Comment: Now it says  Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: So give each subquery an alias.. (Which would be a lot easier if the indentation on that SQL wasn't all over the place)

Comment: @CaiusJard mobile submission :(

Comment: @EoinS yes, sorry I should have made it clear that my comment was directed to Grevak - on the scale of things “subquery needs an alias” is one of those errors/minor typos I would expect an OP to sort out for themselves because it basically involves finding a bracket and putting a letter A after it.. I’ve always had a concern that asking a question here becomes a sort of mental resignation where people are no longer prepared to try debugging anything related to the problem and expect to be delivered a perfect solution :/ Kudos on persevering with mobile SO; I do too and its a pain in the ass :)

Answer (score 0):

your code should look something like this, join the tables properly in the code.
I dont know wich columns and table would suit best for the solution becuse I dont got your full schema. but this should give faster query. Put more columns in the select if you wish.

```
select c_firstName | ' ' | c_lastName, count(rental.c_ID) as rentalCustomer
    from customer
     inner join rental
       on join " connect the both tables"
      innner join rentalprocess
       on "connect rental with rentalprocess"
      inner join copies
         on " connect rentalprocess with copies"
       inner join film
        on "connect copies with film"
    WHERE customer.c_ID=rental.c_ID AND 
    rentalprocess.r_ID=rental.r_ID AND
      rentalprocess.s_ID=copies.s_ID AND 
    film.f_ID=copies.f_ID AND
      f_category=3 AND r_date LIKE "2016-07%"
     group by c_firstName, c_lastName, rental.c_ID
    order by rental.c_ID desc;
```

Comment: If you’re going to this extent, you could go the whole way and pull the join ON conditions out of the WHERE clause - that’s where they were in the 1980s version posted originally!:)